# VSCode Extension fails to load due to @vscode/extension-telemetry

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

An extension ran fine until I upgraded to fix some minor bugs. Since then my extension has stopped working.

Below is the error I am seeing in the Extension Host when the extension loads:

```
2023-12-28 12:36:52.353 [error] Activating extension danish-naglekar.dataverse-devtools failed due to an error:
2023-12-28 12:36:52.353 [error] Error: Cannot find module '@vscode/extension-telemetry'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\XYZ\.vscode\extensions\danish-naglekar.dataverse-devtools-2.1.16\out\extension.js
```

I have @vscode/extension-telemetry under dependency. Local execution and publishing work fine. It only errors when the published extension is loaded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: potentially a case of what happened with https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1612 -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1595 -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43813. try deleting your extension's directory from `~/.vscode/extensions/` and reinstalling?  re: "_until I upgraded to fix some minor bugs_" - what exactly did you upgrade? VS Code? from what version to what version?

Comment: or potentially a case of https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21997. how are you installing npm dependencies? `npm install`? `scripts/npm install`?